# Have Visual Assist X disabled by default?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-assist, visual-assist-x

Is there a way that when Visual Studio Starts have Visual Assist disabled and enable it when I need it?

I mostly work with C# projects and for that I use Resharper. However when I am working with C++ I would like to use Visual Assist and only then I would like to enable Visual Assist.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: IMO, I'd ask Whole Tomato.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Visual Assist for certain file extensions:

1. Open Visual Assist's options menu
2. Click on "Projects and Files"
3. Type .cs to the editbox next to "Extensions to Ignore:"

Hope this helps.